# Long tap instead of simple tap

Tags: ios, swift, behavior, long-press

After I inserted tab bar controller (with reference to another storyboard) I have to long press on tab bar items, table view cells, collection view cells, navigation Item.left Bar Button Item.
 If I use the storyboard with tab bar controller as main storyboard everything works fine. But I have to use a storyboard with login, register, etc view controllers. Then, if I'm successfully logged in I have to show the tab bar items.

Comment: Make the storyboard with the tabbar as the rootViewController at all times. For the other login, register storyboard present it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your app behavior looks like you might have a tab gesture recognizer somewhere in your view that is blocking the single tab from working and that's why you have to do the long pressing.

If this is the case, adding this line to your code where you created the tap should fix it:

```
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```